# splitting date/time field to separate date and time

Tags: parsing, datetime, split, datepicker, getdate

I have a date/time field (i.e. 2018-04-24 10:00:00) that I want to split into separate date and time.  I have the following functions, but it does not work with uib-datepicker since I'm splitting a date/time field like a string:

```
function returnDate(date) {
    var apptDate = date.split(' ')[0];
    return apptDate;
}

function returnTime(date) {
    var apptTime = date.split(' ')[1].substring(0,5);
    var hours24 = parseInt(apptTime.substring(0, 2),10);
    var hours = ((hours24 + 11) % 12) + 1;
    var amPm = hours24 > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    var minutes = apptTime.substring(2);
    return hours + minutes + ' ' + amPm;
}
```

I've also tried to use getDate, getFullYear, getMonth, etc. but I keep getting a TypeError with getDate.

Can someone provide some guidance on this date issue?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `new Date('2018-04-24 10:00:00')` and then geting month year etc afterwords from a date object?

Answer (score 0):

Because between date and time it has a space, so you can get date and time separately by this way.

Method 1 : Split string

```
string date_time = "2018-04-24 10:00:00";

string[] words = date_time.Split(' ');//Split string
string date = words[0];//date = 1st object (before space)
string time = words[1];//time= 2nd object (after space)
```

Method 2 : Using Regular expression

```
string date_time = "2018-04-24 10:00:00";               
string _date = "";    
string _time = "";

Regex date = new Regex(@"([0-9-]+)\s");            
Match match_date = date.Match(date_time);

Regex time = new Regex(@"\s([0-9:]+)");
Match match_time = time.Match(date_time);

//Date
if (match_date.Success)
{
    _date =  match_date.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(_date);
}
//Time
if (match_time.Success)
{
    _time = match_time.Value.Replace(" ","");
    Console.WriteLine(_time);
}
```